# How to set variable to non tf file in terraform?

Tags: terraform

In terraform, I want to create an instance with a script initialized.

```
resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  ...
  user_data = file("./script.sh")
}
```

In script.sh, I want to set a variable in it.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Server name is ': ${var.server_name}
```

In vars.tf

```
variable "server_name" {
  description = "EC2 Server Name"
  type        = string
  default     = "ci server"
}
```

The var syntax is for terraform file, how to pass it to the shell file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having to do too much work, I would say that the best way to do what you want is by using `templatefile` built-in function [1]:

```
  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/script.sh",
    {
      server_name = var.server_name
  })
```

In that case, the script would look like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Server name is ': ${server_name}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you could use `templatefile` function. https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile
[1]:

*templatefile reads the file at the given path and renders its content as a template using a supplied set of template variables.*

Examples:

Given a template file `backends.tftpl` with the following content:

```
%{ for addr in ip_addrs ~}
backend ${addr}:${port}
%{ endfor ~}
```

The templatefile function renders the template:

```
> templatefile("${path.module}/backends.tftpl", { port = 8080, ip_addrs = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"] })
backend 10.0.0.1:8080
backend 10.0.0.2:8080
```

---

In your example you need to change your `script.sh` and make it a template, that refers to`${server_name}` Then an example of execution would be something like this:

```
locals {
  vars = {
    server_name = ${var.server_name}
  }
}

template-script.sh = templatefile("script.sh", vars)

resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  ...
  user_data = file("./template-script.sh")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use template syntax approach directly in user_data configuration. Something like below you can try

```
resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  ...
  user_data = <<-EOT
    echo 'Server name is ':${lookup(aws_instance.instance.tags, "Name")}
  EOT
}
```

Reference :

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file

https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance/issues/59